# Let f be increasing and bounded above. Show that the limit of f when x tends to infinity exists as a real number.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I tried considering the Mean Value Theorem but haven't gotten far.
How could I prove that the limit exists as a real number?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Consider the sequence $f(n)$. This is an increasing, bounded sequence, so it has a limit $L$.

For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$, $|f(n)-L|<\epsilon$. Moreover, since $f(n)$ is increasing and $L\geq f(n)$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for any $x>N$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in the fact that an increasing function has always limit in his domain. Then $\exists lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) $. Being $f$ bounded this limit can't be infinite. Then it's real number.